# Uploading zip file through API Gateway (proxying to ECS) results in corrupted zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway proxying through a VPC into an docker hosted on ECS. No other settings have been done on the API Gateway level. Whenever I upload a zip file and then try to download it it's corrupted. Works fine with things like images etc.

**Example headers for zip file upload**

```
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,el-GR;q=0.8,el;q=0.7
content-length: 482408
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrAyZqb4A6jKc1VBA
```

The code running in the Docker container works fine. Whenever I try to upload directly i.e. without passing through the API Gateway, then it works fine.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

[image: Method Request]
[image: Api Gateway]
[image: Integration Request]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out I was sending the request without all needed headers. It worked fine with Postman. Please check if your request contains these headers.
[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jqSL.png)